# How to create different versions of a website depending on where someone comes from?

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook

This is a little hard to explain.

I want to have a separate home page depending on where people are coming from. For example, if they come from FaceBook, I'd like a special home page for FaceBook users. If they come from Google, I'd like another home page for them.

Here's an example of a website that does this. It will be the normal site at first, but once you've clicked the link thru FaceBook, your browser will only load the FaceBook version.

Normal:
http://www.protectyourhome.com/

From FaceBook:
http://www.protectyourhome.com/Facebook

Any ideas on the codes I'd need for this?

Comment: So basically like a referral link? Just use `GET` to get the name and then design the page accordingly, or you can create separate pages for each referral website (if you don't have many).

Comment: can check the http referrer at server and act accordingly. Research how to do it within whatever server language you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out another way to do this, it's not exactly what I wanted but I made a copy of the website with the index page as indexFB.php and only linked that version of the site with Facebook.